# How to solve ERROR No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: php, ajax, google-api, http-headers

I use a AJAX-Jquery post to calculate the time to get from A to B using Google API.

But i get the error "*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.*"

I've read a lot of posts and tried several solutions. None of them worked.

1. with different variants of headers in my .php page

   ```
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
   ```
2. modifing my .htaccess file:

   ```
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   ```
3. installing Chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US)

The third choise  allowed me to test my code but is not a real solution.
Does anyone succeded to solve this?

Comment: The `access-control-allow-origin` header must be set on the response to your request. So since the `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api` endpoint does not set it, you cannot request it using cross-origin AJAX in the way you're trying.

Comment: I used the solution from [here][1] 
and it worked.


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to need is

## JSONP

JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a communication technique used in JavaScript programs running in web browsers to request data from a server in a different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because of the same-origin policy.

Somewhere inside your AJAX call, you're going to make sure that the `dataSet` is `jsonp`.

Comment: I've tried JSONP but I got this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ".